# passing pointer to an API function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an API function that passes the address of a vector:

```
function_A()
{            
  function_B();
}

function_B()
{
   vector<int> tempVector;
    function(&tempVector[0]); // <---- API function: fills the vector with values
   ...
}
```

The creation of `tempVector` is in `function_B` and it works great.

I want the creation of `tempVector` will be in `function_A` and pass a pointer to it, so other functions in the program will also use the data inside `tempVector`.

I tried to pass the pointer to `tempVector` on several ways to `function(...)`, but I always get errors.

```
function_A()
{         
  vector<int> tempVector;  // <--- creation here   
  function_B(&tempVector); // pass its address 

  //use tempVector
}

function_B(vector<int> * tempVector) // receive its address
{

    function(); // <---- API function: how should I pass tempVector?
   ...
}
```

Comment: Did you try `tempVector->data()` or `&((*tempVector)[0])`?

Comment: How does the `function()` fill the vector if the vector is empty? This smells of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

why pass it as a C pointer and not as C++ reference?

```
function_A()
{         
  vector<int> tempVector;   
  function_B(tempVector);  

  //use tempVector
}

function_B(vector<int>& tempVector) 
{

    function(&tempVector[0]); 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to dereference the pointer as usual like:

```
function_B(vector<int> * tempVector) {
    function(&(*tempVector)[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it like a pointer:

```
function_B(vector<int> * tempVector) // receive its address
{

    function(tempVector);
    ...
}

function(vector<int> * tempVector)
{
    ...
}
```

OR, passit as a variable:

```
function_B(vector<int> * tempVector) // receive its address
{

    function(*tempVector);
    ...
}

function(vector<int> tempVector)
{
    ...
}
```